# Alternância causativo-incoativa

Tags: semântica

> 1. O confinamento trancou mais da metade da humanidade em suas casas.
> 2. Mais da metade da humanidade está trancada em suas casas pelo confinamento.
> 3. Mais da metade da humanidade se trancou em suas casas.

Explique a passivização e a alternância causativo-incoativa como propriedades sintáticas e porque isto é possível com os exemplos acima.

Comment: Olá Lana, bem-vinda. Isso parece um exercício de escola. É bom que venhas procurar ajuda onde tens dificuldades, mas é também adequado e necessário que progridas no exercício por ti própria.

Comment: Que dúvida **concreta** tens? Deves ser clara na pergunta que queres fazer - mais do que expor um problema geral de gramática. Isola a dificuldade: queres talvez saber o que é a alternância causativo-incoativa?; ou talvez queiras aprofundar algum pormenor concreto dela?; ou se calhar sabes a sua definição, mas não como se aplica a alguma dessas frases... Até que ponto chegaste nesse problema que tens, e qual é a dúvida concreta que tens? Talvez te possamos desbloquear esse nó que tenhas encontrado, e assim consigas progredir. :)

Comment: @ANeves if I had to guess the original poster isn't a native Portuguese speaker and may not be able to easily understand your comments. I've seen questions like this from university level students (normally from Asia) taking Portuguese as a second language. Notice that while the question is grammatically very formal and sophisticated, it is based on simple sentences with elementary vocabulary.

Comment: @bad_coder my opinion is different from yours. But **Lana Woon**, we're all available to explain anything that you don't understand. :) Just ask, eh? No problem. Even if your English is weak and you need to use Korean or some other distant language, we can translate and we'll manage. Don't worry!